# OAUth2 ASP.NET invalid_grant

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I am trying to implement OAUTH2 for my web application but even though signing in to the application works, refresh tokens result in an HTTP 400 "invalid_grant".
Specifically, the project is an ASP.NET WebAPI with OWIN OAuth provider. This has been killing me for days without luck so any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you correctly set `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.RefreshTokenProvider`?

If you need a sample, Katana's sandbox project contains a minimal implementation showing how you can easily configure it to protect and serialize refresh tokens using the data protection block (machine keys on IIS): https://github.com/jchannon/katanaproject/blob/master/tests/Katana.Sandbox.WebServer/Startup.cs#L169-L173

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions  {
    RefreshTokenProvider = new AuthenticationTokenProvider {
        OnCreate = CreateRefreshToken,
        OnReceive = ReceiveRefreshToken,
    }
});

private void CreateRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context) {
    context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
}

private void ReceiveRefreshToken(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context) {
    context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);
}
```

If it still doesn't work, try enabling tracing to determine the root cause of the `invalid_grant` error: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 0):

We were getting the same issue when deploying the `AuthorizationServer` on Azure and trying to access it through **localhost**. 
Later we deployed all 3:

- AuthorizationServer
- AuthrizationCodeGrant
- Resource Server

Made required changes in the `Constants\Paths.cs` for the deployed URLs. 
Even after this it did not work. But once we changed all the paths to **HTTPS** it all started working smoothly.

Please try that in case you are still stuck.